# Querying multiple sensors regularly using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, memory, child-process

I need to fetch the values of about 200 sensors every 15 seconds or so. To fetch the values I simply need to make an HTTP call with basic authentication and parse the response. The catch is that these sensors might be on slow connection so I need to wait at least 5 seconds for one sensor (but usually they respond a lot quicker, but there's always some that are slow and timeout).
So right now I have the following setup for that:

There is a NodeJS process that is connected to my DB and knows all about the sensors. It checks regularly to see if there are new ones or there are some that got deleted. It spawns a child process for every sensor, and in case the child process dies it restarts it. Also it kills it if the sensor gets deleted. The child process makes the HTTP call to its sensor with a 5 second timeout value and if it receives the value, saves it to Redis. Also it is in an infinite loop with a 15 seconds setTimeout. And there is a third process that copies all the values from Redis to the main MySQL DB.
So that has been a working solution for half a year, but after a major system upgrade (from Ubuntu 14.04 to 18.04 and thus every package upgraded as well) it seems to leak some memory and I can't seem to figure out where. 
After starting out, the processes summarised take about 1.5GB of memory. But after a day or so this goes up to 3GB and so on and before running out of memory I need to kill all node processes and restart the whole thing.

So now I am trying to figure out more efficient methods to achieve the same result (query around 2-300 URLs every 15 sec and store the result in MySQL). At the moment I'm thinking of ditching Redis and the child processes will communicate with their master process and the master process will write to MySQL directly. This way I don't need to load the Redis library into every child process and that might save me some time. 
So I need ideas on how to reduce memory usage for that application (I'm limited to PHP and NodeJS, mainly because of my knowledge, so writing a native daemon might be out of the question)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was easier than I thought. I had to rewrite the child process into a native bash script and that brought down the memory usage to almost being zero.